# How to name dynamic radio buttons with flask and wtforms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a simple yes/no reply form with multiple entries.  I have a database with 1,000 names and the team manager is allowed to respond yes/no for all of their team members.   Yet, each yes/no response will get stored in a separate table aligned with that specific person.   Every user has a unique ID in the database.  I don't know how to create a dynamic radio button name with flask and wtforms.

rsvp.html:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th width="300">Name</th>
<th width="200">Accept</th>
<th width="200">Decline</th></tr>
{% for guest in guests %}
  <tr><td align="center">
    {{ guest.first_name }} {{ guest.last_name }}
  </td>
  {% for subfield in form.name1 %}
    <td align="center">
      {{ subfield }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Obviously this won't work because if you have 6 team members listed, all radio buttons will have name="name1".  I need to associate the radio button name with the ID of that user, perhaps name="name23", name="name67", etc.   Where 23 and 67 are two ID's in the database.

forms.py:

```
class RsvpForm(Form):
    name1 = RadioField('', choices=[('yes','YES'), ('no','NO')])
    name2 = RadioField('', choices=[('yes','YES'), ('no','NO')])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit RSVP")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

views.py:

```
@app.route('/rsvp', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def rsvp():
    form = RsvpForm()
    if 'guestid' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    guests = Guest.query.filter_by(team=session['team']).all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            for i in guests:
                gid = i.id
                rsvpi = Rsvp(gid, form.name['gid'].data)
                db.session.add(rsvpi)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('rsvp'))
        else:
            return "Form didn't validate"

    return render_template('rsvp.html', form=form, guests=guests)
```

Comment: Do they *need* to be radio buttons or can they be checkboxes / a multi-select?

Comment: Well the response is Yes -or- No per team member, so a radio button works best.  A simple (single) select pulldown could also work, but I'd still have the issue of naming the form inputs dynamically.